# get the result from google search using apache client in java

Tags: java

How to get search result using HttpClient here is my code

```
HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/search/?q=my_query");
```

But it is giving me response

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Please give me some help.
Thank you.

Comment: *http://www.google.com/search/?q=my_query* is really **Not Found**. I would've posted a question if it actually had found it.. You probably wanted to have `#` instead of `?`.

Comment: If an answer worked for you, please accept it for others users to know.

Answer (score 3):

Use `http://www.google.com/#q=my_query` instead, that should work.

Comment: yeah it's working but i m not getting any link from this response, what is the accurate query to get the links from google result. please tell me

Comment: Seems that you can't : Google seems to retrieve the links with crypted ajax loads once the page is loaded on the user's browser, to prevent link stealing (fair enough).

Comment: so there is no way i can get links from google search result, i have also used google ajax api but it allows me only 100 req per day, i m really stuckin here, don't know what to do, i m not getting any solution please if u know any solution please help me.